# Как сделать миграции после добавления поля?

Tags: django

Всем привет, добавил новые поля в модель, пытаюсь смигрировать их, выскакивает ошибка

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column "name" of relation "employees_employee" already exists
```

Пытался делать фейковую миграцию предпоследней миграции

```
python src/manage.py migrate --fake employees 0009_rename_socialaccount_socialnetwork
```

После этого делал обычную и получаю такую же ошибку что поле уже существует.
Удалять все миграции не вариант. Подскажите как можно это решить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего есть какая то не согласованность таблиц в БД и миграций Djnago. Django пытается создать поле, которое уже существует. Поэтому при создании миграции с новым полем нужно будет заменить (в файле новой миграции) [AddField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/migration-operations/#addfield) -> [AlterField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/migration-operations/#alterfield). Хочу предупредить, что несогласованность БД и миграцией в будущем может сильно мешать. Теоретически правильным решением будет, создать миграцию (makemigrations), которая создаст это поле, затем выполнить `migrate --fake`, затем создать ещё одну пустую миграцию, скопировать в неё код предыдущей миграции (с поправкой на dependenses, чтобы она ссылалась на прошлую миграцию) и заменить AddField -> AlterField.